# Bookmark pdf and djvu files

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, djvu

1. For pdf: How can I create outlines/bookmarks
   for and merge them into pdf files in
   either terminal or in GUI application in Ubuntu?
2. For djvu: I know how to do the same thing for
   djvu files in terminal using
   djvused. I was wondering if there is
   some gui based application that can
   create bookmarks/outlines for djvu
   files more quickly?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the second part of your question I would recommend [djvusmooth](http://packages.ubuntu.com/djvusmooth).

for the first part of your question I would suggest [pdfchain](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pdfchain) should cover your requirements

both are available from the Software Centre.

I personally use a command in terminal to extract text:

```
pdftotext -layout *.pdf anyname.txt
```

this will export the text of the pdf to a file meaning you can edit the text in a text editor.

Comment: @Allan: Thanks! pdfchain seems not provide editing bookmarks/outlines of a pdf file. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Tim Hi I have found an alternative that you can try called jpdfbookmarks its not in the Software Centre, so you will have to install it manually I will add the steps to do this to my answer soon

Comment: @Allan: Thanks! I have tried jpdfbookmarks. It can make bookmarks in GUI mode. However it seems a software just for making bookmarks, not for other common requirements on pdf files. For example, I cannot or don't know how to select texts (for copying). Am I missing something?

Comment: @tim: I use a command line which extracts the text to a text file I can then choose copy what I want from it although you can do this from evince the default pdf viewer for Ubuntu as well.

Comment: @Allan: (1) what is the command to extract? (2) do you mean opening the file in jpdfbookmarks for bookmarking, and also open it in evince to select text?

Comment: @tim (1) added to answer (2) I use a combination of programs to extract various parts of a pdf.

Comment: @Allan: Thanks! So after editing in the exported text file, is it possible to import the edited text back into the pdf file?

Comment: Unfortunately, Djvusmooth is Python 2-only. I really liked it... Do you have any other / new recommendations? Thanks!