# Renumbering the pages in a .pdf

Tags: printing, pdf, latex

I'm trying to organize a number of .pdf files from a course into a single book.  I've managed to combine them all into a single large .pdf correctly, but now I have that the individual numbering of each .pdf isn't internally consistent.  By this, I mean that:

The first .pdf is labeled from 1 -  12 in the bottom (or whatever numbers).

The second .pdf (starting on page 13) page numbers at all.

The third .pdf (starting on page 18) is labeled from 1 - 5 in the center of the bottom.

The label locations are "standard Latex" ones to the best of my knowledge, if that makes it any easier.  Is there a way I could go through and relabel this so, when I print out the large .pdf, it'll display from 1 - 300 (or however long it is) sequentially, with the numbers "in consistent places" as well?

Edit:  [This blogpost](http://cazencott.info/index.php/post/2015/04/30/Numbering-PDF-Pages) goes over adding page numbers, and it works.  The issue now is many pages are double numbered (this adds new numbering, but doesn't remove old number).  Is there a way to remove numbering from pages?

Comment: This maybe? [Renumber pages of a PDF](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32048/renumber-pages-of-a-pdf)

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't change the numbers that appear when you view the .pdf